# Get Filename From copy query without stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
copy into EMPLOYEE_SKILL(
    FILE_NAME_FULL_S3_PATH, 
    LINE_NUMBER, 
    SKILL_ID, 
    EMP_ID, 
    SKILL_NAME, 
    SKILL_LEVEL ) 
from (select 
    metadata$filename, 
    metadata$file_row_number, 
    t.$1, 
    t.$2,
    t.$3,
    t.$4 
    from s3://test_bucket/emp/ )t 
credentials=(aws_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' aws_secret_key='YYYYYYYYYY') 
file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|'skip_header = 1) 
on_error = 'continue';
```

facing issue with this query.
Can anyone help me for getting filename from copy query without stage

Tried to get filename from copy query without stage

Comment: So what’s the actual issue you are facing? What happens if you just run the SELECT statement?

Comment: Select statement result error

Comment: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 115 unexpected 't'.

Comment: Hi @Dharani, Issue is due to the alias name outside of the select:
0

copy into EMPLOYEE_SKILL(
    FILE_NAME_FULL_S3_PATH, 
    LINE_NUMBER, 
    SKILL_ID, 
    EMP_ID, 
    SKILL_NAME, 
    SKILL_LEVEL ) 
from (select 
    metadata$filename, 
    metadata$file_row_number, 
    t.$1, 
    t.$2,
    t.$3,
    t.$4 
    from s3://test_bucket/emp/ )t 
credentials=(aws_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' aws_secret_key='YYYYYYYYYY') 
file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|'skip_header = 1) 
on_error = 'continue';

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with below code, I could see alias name is outside of the select:

```
copy into EMPLOYEE_SKILL(
    FILE_NAME_FULL_S3_PATH, 
    LINE_NUMBER, 
    SKILL_ID, 
    EMP_ID, 
    SKILL_NAME, 
    SKILL_LEVEL ) 
from (select 
    metadata$filename, 
    metadata$file_row_number, 
    t.$1, 
    t.$2,
    t.$3,
    t.$4 
    from s3://test_bucket/emp/ t) 
credentials=(aws_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX' aws_secret_key='YYYYYYYYYY') 
file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = '|'skip_header = 1) 
on_error = 'continue';
```